# Running a website on a LAN only

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, mac-osx, local-area-network

This is a big question, so I'm only looking for a high-level overview answer to help me research the bits I don't know.

Essentially the problem is this: I need to take a dedicated Mac Mini (or similar macOS machine) and use it to host a website that's only accessible to those on the same local network.

My first instinct was to buy a domain (and certificate) and point it to a local address (eg. 10.10.10.152) that I know my server will be located at. So that way anyone trying to access that domain will be redirected locally to my website if they're on the right network.

Will this work? If so, what are the major steps in taking a domain, installing a certificate, and pointing it to a local IP?

Comment: Are you OK with strictly config based approach (use apache itself to limit the visitors access)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, I think so. Because it's hosted on a local IP nobody will be able to access it externally anyway

Comment: Missing basics professionals - which this site is for - would know. Belongs to superuser.com

Comment: @TomTom Didn't want to go into more detail as a) I don't know some of them, due to how this project has been run, and b) it's quite a big subject that each part could probably be its own question. But I can add more, if there's something specific you'd like to know?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Those are still fundamental issues, like "what does DNS do" or - and that is utterly not the level of your normal questions "what are the steps in taking a domain" and "pointing it  to a local IP"? Professional admin. This is not a beginner topic - this is intern level.

Comment: @TomTom Lol. I'm basically looking for a sanity check. I know how to make a domain point to an IP X-) That would fall pretty much in the "low level" which I specifically said I didn't want. Of course typical ranking users on SF like to look down and assume the worst in all questions... Sigh. It'll be sad when the SO universe is finally dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> buy a domain (and certificate) and point it to a local address (eg. 10.10.10.152) that I know my server will be located at. So that way anyone trying to access that domain will be redirected locally to my website if they're on the right network.

That would work, but there's absolutely no necessity to buy anything.

You can set up local DNS for e.g. *service.example.org* (if you own *example.org*), or *service.lan* without a domain of your own. Point the A record to your private web server.

If you require HTTPS (TLS), you can either self-sign a certificate and explicitly trust that certificate from each of your clients, or you start a new CA (takes just a minute with OpenSSL), sign a certificate for *service.lan* and deploy the CA root certificate to your clients as trust anchor.

Comment: I would definitely go that way.
Buying an external domain and certificate for a purely internal website seems illogical.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the helpful advice. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments discussion you can use for example Apache and set something like:
using the module `mod_authz_host` and the `Require` directives.

```
<Directory /var/www/web/>
  Require host localhost
  Require ip 127.0.0.1
  Require ip 192.168.0
</Directory>
```

(above I suppose your local network is `192.168.0.0/24`)

This config will limit the access to `localhost/127.0.0.1` and all the hosts in network `192.168.0.0/24`

Comment: I think I'll just limit it to a predictable static IP. There's no reason to widen it beyond that

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt, no problem, you can list only the required IPs and not the entire network (just like 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if arrived at the idea of registering/configuring a domain and buying a certificate by accident or design - but in the absence of experience with network configuration and systems administration, this is the probably the shortest route to your goal.

Alternative approaches would be to

- provision the website on the internet, only allow access the ACME path and get a free certificate from LetsEncrypt (which also requires that you have a valid public DNS record - hence a reasonably static IP or dynamic DNS service)
- build your own certificate authority, distribute the CA cert to the clients and use that to sign a certificate for the service
- or not use TLS at all (not recommended).

You will need a registered domain with records to obtain a certificate from a third party certificate authority. If you choose one of the other methods, then you don't need a registered domain / publicly accessible DNS records - you could (for eaxmple) use dnsmasq for your internal DNS (easy to provision overrides of specific DNS names).

As long as your internet connection does not permit external access to the IP address of the host you don't need additional security controls, but adding them now might prevent accidents in future.